# How is this Hamiltonian diagonalized?

Tags: condensed-matter, hamiltonian, parity

In this [paper](https://doi.org/10.1088/1751-8121/aa785a), they have a Hamiltonian of the form

\begin{equation}
H=\begin{pmatrix}
z\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}+g(z+\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}) & \gamma z\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}+\Delta\\
\gamma z\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}+\Delta & z\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}-g(z+\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z})
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

And they claim that a unitary transformation given by
$$\mathcal U=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\
\mathcal T & -\mathcal T
\end{pmatrix} \quad\quad \text{where } \mathcal Tu(z)=u(-z) \text{ is the Parity operator}$$
diagonalizes the Hamiltonian.

Here is my attempt to see this.

$$\mathcal U^{-1}=\frac {1 }{\sqrt 2}\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & \frac{1}{\mathcal T} \\
 1 & -\frac{1}{\mathcal T} \\
\end{array}
\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & \mathcal T \\
 1 & -\mathcal T \\
\end{array}
\right) \quad\quad \text{where I used } \mathcal T^2=\mathbb{1}$$

Now,
\begin{align}
\mathcal U^{-1}H\mathcal U&=\frac12 \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & \mathcal T \\
 1 & -\mathcal T \\
\end{array}
\right)\begin{pmatrix}
z\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}+g(z+\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}) & \gamma z\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}+\Delta\\
\gamma z\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}+\Delta & z\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}-g(z+\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z})
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\
\mathcal T & -\mathcal T
\end{pmatrix}\\
&=\frac12 \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & \mathcal T \\
 1 & -\mathcal T \\
\end{array}
\right) \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{d}{\text{dz}} g+\mathcal T(\Delta +\gamma  z\frac{d}{\text{dz}})+z\frac{d}{\text{dz}}+g z & \frac{d}{\text{dz}} g-\mathcal T(\Delta +\gamma  z\frac{d}{\text{dz}})+z\frac{d}{\text{dz}}+g z \\
 \Delta +\mathcal T(-\frac{d}{\text{dz}} g+z\frac{d}{\text{dz}}-g z)+\gamma  z\frac{d}{\text{dz}} & \Delta -\mathcal T(-\frac{d}{\text{dz}} g+z\frac{d}{\text{dz}}-g z)+\gamma  z\frac{d}{\text{dz}} \\
\end{array}
\right)\\
&=\frac12 \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \mathcal T(\Delta +\mathcal T(-\frac{d}{\text{dz}} g+z\frac{d}{\text{dz}}-g z)+\gamma  z\frac{d}{\text{dz}})+\frac{d}{\text{dz}} g+\mathcal T(\Delta +\gamma  z\frac{d}{\text{dz}})+z\frac{d}{\text{dz}}+g z & \mathcal T(\Delta -\mathcal T(-\frac{d}{\text{dz}} g+z\frac{d}{\text{dz}}-g z)+\gamma  z\frac{d}{\text{dz}})+\frac{d}{\text{dz}} g-\mathcal T(\Delta +\gamma  z\frac{d}{\text{dz}})+z\frac{d}{\text{dz}}+g z \\
 -\mathcal T(\Delta +\mathcal T(-\frac{d}{\text{dz}} g+z\frac{d}{\text{dz}}-g z)+\gamma  z\frac{d}{\text{dz}})+\frac{d}{\text{dz}} g+\mathcal T(\Delta +\gamma  z\frac{d}{\text{dz}})+z\frac{d}{\text{dz}}+g z & -\mathcal T(\Delta -\mathcal T(-\frac{d}{\text{dz}} g+z\frac{d}{\text{dz}}-g z)+\gamma  \frac{d}{f\text{dz}} z)+\frac{d}{\text{dz}} g-\mathcal T(\Delta +\gamma  z\frac{d}{\text{dz}})+z\frac{d}{\text{dz}}+g z \\
\end{array}
\right)
\end{align}

The off-diagonal term on the top right is
\begin{align}
&\mathcal T(\Delta -\mathcal T(-\frac{d}{\text{dz}} g+z\frac{d}{\text{dz}}-g z)+\gamma  z\frac{d}{\text{dz}})+\frac{d}{\text{dz}} g-\mathcal T(\Delta +\gamma  z\frac{d}{\text{dz}})+z\frac{d}{\text{dz}}+g z\\
&=\mathcal T(\Delta +\gamma z \frac{d}{dz})+\frac{d}{\text{dz}} g-z\frac{d}{\text{dz}}+g z+\frac{d}{\text{dz}} g-\mathcal T(\Delta +\gamma  z\frac{d}{\text{dz}})+z\frac{d}{\text{dz}}+g z\\
&=2g\left(z+\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d z} \right)
\end{align}

I can't see how the non-diagonal terms are zero. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\newcommand{\du}{\mathrm{1\!\!1}}$
$\newcommand{\e}{\boldsymbol=}$
$\newcommand{\m}{\boldsymbol-}$
$\newcommand{\p}{\boldsymbol+}$
$\newcommand{\qqlaqq}{\qquad\boldsymbol{-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!\longrightarrow}\qquad}$
We have the Hamiltonian
\begin{equation}
\mathcal H\e
\begin{bmatrix}
z\dfrac{\mathrm d }{\mathrm d z}\p g\left(z\p\dfrac{\mathrm d }{\mathrm d z}\right) & \gamma z\dfrac{\mathrm d }{\mathrm d z}\p\Delta\vphantom{\tfrac{\tfrac{a}{b}}{\tfrac{a}{b}}}\\
\gamma z\dfrac{\mathrm d }{\mathrm d z}\p\Delta &
 z\dfrac{\mathrm d }{\mathrm d z}\m g\left(z\p\dfrac{\mathrm d }{\mathrm d z}\right)\vphantom{\tfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{\tfrac{a}{b}}}
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{01}\label{01}  
\end{equation}
For convenience define the operators
\begin{equation}
z\dfrac{\mathrm d }{\mathrm d z}\boldsymbol\equiv \mathcal A\,,\qquad g\left(z\p\dfrac{\mathrm d }{\mathrm d z}\right)\boldsymbol\equiv\mathcal B 
\tag{02}\label{02}  
\end{equation}
Then our Hamiltonian is simplified to
\begin{equation}
\mathcal H\e
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathcal A\p\mathcal B  & \gamma \mathcal A\p\Delta\vphantom{\tfrac{\tfrac{a}{b}}{\tfrac{a}{b}}}\\
\gamma \mathcal A\p\Delta &
\mathcal A\m\mathcal B\vphantom{\tfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{\tfrac{a}{b}}}
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{03}\label{03}  
\end{equation}
We must prove that the canonical Fulton–Gouterman transformation
\begin{equation}
\mathcal U\boldsymbol=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}
\begin{bmatrix}
\hphantom{\boldsymbol-}\mathrm  I  & \hphantom{\boldsymbol-}\mathrm I\vphantom{\tfrac{\tfrac{a}{b}}{\tfrac{a}{b}}}\hphantom{-}\\
\hphantom{\boldsymbol-}\mathcal T  & \boldsymbol-\mathcal T\vphantom{\tfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{\tfrac{a}{b}}}\hphantom{\boldsymbol-}
\end{bmatrix}\,,\quad
\mathcal U^{\boldsymbol-1}\boldsymbol=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}
\begin{bmatrix}
\hphantom{\boldsymbol-}\mathrm  I  & \hphantom{\boldsymbol-}\mathcal T\vphantom{\tfrac{\tfrac{a}{b}}{\tfrac{a}{b}}}\hphantom{-}\\
\hphantom{\boldsymbol-}\mathrm I  & \boldsymbol-\mathcal T\vphantom{\tfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{\tfrac{a}{b}}}\hphantom{\boldsymbol-}
\end{bmatrix}\,,\quad
\mathcal T f\left(z\right)\boldsymbol=f\left(\boldsymbol-z\right)
\tag{04}\label{04}    
\end{equation}
where $\:\mathcal T\:$ the parity transformation, transforms the Hamiltonian \eqref{03} onto diagonal form.

We have

<sup>\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\mathcal U^{\boldsymbol-1}\mathcal H\,\mathcal U & \boldsymbol=\frac{1}{2}
\begin{bmatrix}
\hphantom{\boldsymbol-}\mathrm  I  & \hphantom{\boldsymbol-}\mathcal T\vphantom{\left(z\boldsymbol+\dfrac{\mathrm d }{\mathrm d z}\right)\tfrac{\tfrac{a}{b}}{\tfrac{a}{b}}}\hphantom{-}\\
\hphantom{\boldsymbol-}\mathrm I  & \boldsymbol-\mathcal T\vphantom{\tfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{\tfrac{a}{b}}}\hphantom{\boldsymbol-}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathcal A\boldsymbol+\mathcal B  & \gamma \mathcal A\boldsymbol+\Delta\vphantom{\left(z\boldsymbol+\dfrac{\mathrm d }{\mathrm d z}\right)\tfrac{\tfrac{a}{b}}{\tfrac{a}{b}}}\\
\gamma \mathcal A\boldsymbol+\Delta &
\mathcal A\boldsymbol-\mathcal B\vphantom{\tfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{\tfrac{a}{b}}}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\hphantom{\boldsymbol-}\mathrm  I  & \hphantom{\boldsymbol-}\mathrm I\vphantom{\left(z\boldsymbol+\dfrac{\mathrm d }{\mathrm d z}\right)\tfrac{\tfrac{a}{b}}{\tfrac{a}{b}}}\hphantom{-}\\
\hphantom{\boldsymbol-}\mathcal T  & \boldsymbol-\mathcal T\vphantom{\tfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{\tfrac{a}{b}}}\hphantom{\boldsymbol-}
\end{bmatrix}\\
&\boldsymbol=\frac{1}{2}
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathcal A\boldsymbol+\mathcal B\boldsymbol+\mathcal T \left(\gamma \mathcal A\boldsymbol+\Delta\right)  & \gamma \mathcal A\boldsymbol+\Delta\boldsymbol+\mathcal T \left(\mathcal A\boldsymbol-\mathcal B\right)\vphantom{\left(z\boldsymbol+\dfrac{\mathrm d }{\mathrm d z}\right)\tfrac{\tfrac{a}{b}}{\tfrac{a}{b}}}\\
\mathcal A\boldsymbol+\mathcal B\boldsymbol-\mathcal T \left(\gamma \mathcal A\boldsymbol+\Delta\right)  &
\gamma \mathcal A\boldsymbol+\Delta\boldsymbol-\mathcal T \left(\mathcal A\boldsymbol-\mathcal B\right)\vphantom{\tfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{\tfrac{a}{b}}}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\hphantom{\boldsymbol-}\mathrm  I  & \hphantom{\boldsymbol-}\mathrm I\vphantom{\left(z\boldsymbol+\dfrac{\mathrm d }{\mathrm d z}\right)\tfrac{\tfrac{a}{b}}{\tfrac{a}{b}}}\hphantom{-}\\
\hphantom{\boldsymbol-}\mathcal T  & \boldsymbol-\mathcal T\vphantom{\tfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{\tfrac{a}{b}}}\hphantom{\boldsymbol-}
\end{bmatrix}\\
&\boldsymbol=\frac{1}{2}
\begin{bmatrix}
\hphantom{\boldsymbol-}\mathcal H_{11} & \hphantom{\boldsymbol-}\mathcal H_{12}\vphantom{\left(z\boldsymbol+\dfrac{\mathrm d }{\mathrm d z}\right)\tfrac{\tfrac{a}{b}}{\tfrac{a}{b}}}\hphantom{-}\\
\hphantom{\boldsymbol-}\mathcal H_{21}  & \hphantom{\boldsymbol-}\mathcal H_{22}\vphantom{\tfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{\tfrac{a}{b}}}\hphantom{\boldsymbol-}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{split}  
\tag{05}\label{05}     
\end{equation}</sup>

where

<sup>\begin{align}
\mathcal H_{11} & \boldsymbol=
\mathcal A\boldsymbol+\mathcal B\boldsymbol+\mathcal T \left(\gamma \mathcal A\boldsymbol+\Delta\right)\boldsymbol+\left(\gamma \mathcal A\boldsymbol+\Delta\right)\mathcal T \boldsymbol+\mathcal T \left(\mathcal A\boldsymbol-\mathcal B\right)\mathcal T
\tag{06a}\label{06a}\\
\mathcal H_{22} & \boldsymbol=
\mathcal A\boldsymbol+\mathcal B\boldsymbol-\mathcal T \left(\gamma \mathcal A\boldsymbol+\Delta\right)\boldsymbol-\left(\gamma \mathcal A\boldsymbol+\Delta\right)\mathcal T \boldsymbol+\mathcal T \left(\mathcal A\boldsymbol-\mathcal B\right)\mathcal T
\tag{06b}\label{06b}\\
\mathcal H_{12}&\boldsymbol=
\mathcal A\boldsymbol+\mathcal B\boldsymbol+\mathcal T \left(\gamma \mathcal A\boldsymbol+\Delta\right)\boldsymbol-\left(\gamma \mathcal A\boldsymbol+\Delta\right)\mathcal T \boldsymbol-\mathcal T \left(\mathcal A\boldsymbol-\mathcal B\right)\mathcal T
\tag{06c}\label{06c}\\
\mathcal H_{21}&\boldsymbol=
\mathcal A\boldsymbol+\mathcal B\boldsymbol-\mathcal T \left(\gamma \mathcal A\boldsymbol+\Delta\right)\boldsymbol+\left(\gamma \mathcal A\boldsymbol+\Delta\right)\mathcal T \boldsymbol-\mathcal T \left(\mathcal A\boldsymbol-\mathcal B\right)\mathcal T
\tag{06d}\label{06d}
\end{align}</sup>

It could be proved that $\:\mathcal T\:$ commutes with $\:\mathcal A\:$ and anti-commutes with $\:\mathcal B\:$
\begin{equation}
\mathcal T \mathcal A\boldsymbol=  \mathcal A\,\mathcal T\,,\qquad \mathcal T \mathcal B\boldsymbol{=-} \mathcal B\,\mathcal T 
\tag{07}\label{07}  
\end{equation}
so

<sup>\begin{align}
\tfrac{1}{2}\mathcal H_{11} & \boldsymbol=
\mathcal A\boldsymbol+\mathcal B\boldsymbol+\left(\gamma \mathcal A\boldsymbol+\Delta\right)\mathcal T\boldsymbol=z\dfrac{\mathrm d }{\mathrm d z}\boldsymbol+g\left(z\boldsymbol+\dfrac{\mathrm d }{\mathrm d z}\right)\boldsymbol + \left(\gamma z\dfrac{\mathrm d }{\mathrm d z}\boldsymbol+\Delta\right)\mathcal T \boldsymbol\equiv \mathcal H_{\boldsymbol+}
\tag{08a}\label{08a}\\
\tfrac{1}{2}\mathcal H_{22} & \boldsymbol=
\mathcal A\boldsymbol+\mathcal B\boldsymbol-\left(\gamma \mathcal A\boldsymbol+\Delta\right)\mathcal T\boldsymbol=z\dfrac{\mathrm d }{\mathrm d z}\boldsymbol+g\left(z\boldsymbol+\dfrac{\mathrm d }{\mathrm d z}\right)\boldsymbol- \left(\gamma z\dfrac{\mathrm d }{\mathrm d z}\boldsymbol+\Delta\right)\mathcal T \boldsymbol\equiv \mathcal H_{\boldsymbol-}
\tag{08b}\label{08b}\\
\tfrac{1}{2}\mathcal H_{12}&\boldsymbol=
\mathcal O
\tag{08c}\label{08c}\\
\tfrac{1}{2}\mathcal H_{21} & \boldsymbol=
\mathcal O
\tag{08d}\label{08d}
\end{align}</sup>

that is

<sup>\begin{align}
\mathcal U^{\boldsymbol-1}\mathcal H\,\mathcal U & \boldsymbol=
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathcal H_{\boldsymbol+}  & \mathcal O\vphantom{\tfrac{\tfrac{a}{b}}{\tfrac{a}{b}}}\\
\mathcal O &
\mathcal H_{\boldsymbol-}\vphantom{\tfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{\tfrac{a}{b}}}
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{09}\label{09}\\
& \boldsymbol=
\begin{bmatrix}
z\dfrac{\mathrm d }{\mathrm d z}\boldsymbol+g\left(z\boldsymbol+\dfrac{\mathrm d }{\mathrm d z}\right)\boldsymbol + \left(\gamma z\dfrac{\mathrm d }{\mathrm d z}\boldsymbol+\Delta\right)\mathcal T  & \mathcal O\vphantom{\tfrac{\tfrac{a}{b}}{\tfrac{a}{b}}}\\
\mathcal O &
z\dfrac{\mathrm d }{\mathrm d z}\boldsymbol+g\left(z\boldsymbol+\dfrac{\mathrm d }{\mathrm d z}\right)\boldsymbol- \left(\gamma z\dfrac{\mathrm d }{\mathrm d z}\boldsymbol+\Delta\right)\mathcal T \vphantom{\tfrac{\dfrac{a}{b}}{\tfrac{a}{b}}}
\end{bmatrix}  
\end{align}</sup>

$=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!=\!$

**ADDENDUM**

The Hamiltonian $\:\mathcal H\:$ of equation \eqref{01} is of the Fulton-Gouterman type according to the following definition

---

**Definition**  A 2×2 hermitian operator $\:\hat H\:$ is
said to be of the *Fulton-Gouterman type*, and denoted
by $\:\hat H_{FG}\:$, if

1. $\hat H\:$ is similar to
   \begin{equation}
   \hat H_{FG}\boldsymbol=A\du\boldsymbol+B\sigma_1\boldsymbol+C\sigma_2\boldsymbol+D\sigma_3
   \tag{A-01}\label{A-01}   
   \end{equation}
2. there is a hermitian operator $\:\hat{\rm R}\:$ such that
   \begin{equation}
   \left[\hat{\rm R},A\right]\boldsymbol=\left[\hat{\rm R}, B\right]\boldsymbol=0\,,\quad \left\{\hat{\rm R},C\right\}\boldsymbol=\left\{\hat{\rm R},D\right\}\boldsymbol=0
   \tag{A-02}\label{A-02}   
   \end{equation}
   where $\:\left[\,,\right]\:$ and $\:\left\{\,,\right\}\:$ denote the conventional commutator and anticommutator.

---

Note that any 2×2 hermitian operator $\:\hat H\:$ can
be expressed in the form
\begin{equation}
\hat H\boldsymbol=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{3}h_j\sigma_j\, \quad h_j\boldsymbol=\tfrac12\mathrm{Tr}\left(\hat H\sigma_j\right), 
\tag{A-03}\label{A-03}   
\end{equation}
where $\:h_j$’s are one-dimensional operators in a suitable
Hilbert space and here and elsewhere the standard representation
of the Pauli matrices $\:\sigma_j\:,j = 1,2,3,$ is assumed. For the sake of compactness, we set $\:\sigma_0:\boldsymbol=\du\:$ in summation formulas, with $\:\du\:$ being the unit matrix.

With respect to the diagonalization of a Fulton-Gouterman type hermitian operator $\:\hat H_{FG}\:$
the following theorem is valid

---

**Theorem** Any $\:\hat H_{FG}\:$ given by equation \eqref{A-01} can be diagonalized
by means of a unitary transformation,
\begin{equation}
U_{FG}\hat H_{FG}U_{FG}^{\boldsymbol-1}\boldsymbol=\left(A\boldsymbol+D\right)\du\boldsymbol+B\hat{\rm R}\,\sigma_3\boldsymbol-\mathrm iC\hat{\rm R}\,\sigma_3
\tag{A-04}\label{A-04}   
\end{equation}
induced by
\begin{equation}
U_{FG}\boldsymbol=\frac12\left[\left(1\boldsymbol+\hat{\rm R}\right)U_{13}\boldsymbol+\left(1\boldsymbol-\hat{\rm R}\right)U_{2}^{\boldsymbol-1}\right]
\tag{A-05}\label{A-05}   
\end{equation}
where $\:U_{13}\boldsymbol=\left(\sigma_1\boldsymbol+\sigma_3\right)/\sqrt{2}\:$ and $\:U_{2}\boldsymbol=\left(\du\boldsymbol+\mathrm i\sigma_2\right)/\sqrt{2}$.

---

The diagonal elements of the diagonalized Hamiltonian are
\begin{equation}
\hat{\rm L}_{\boldsymbol\pm}\boldsymbol=A\boldsymbol+D\boldsymbol\pm\left(B\boldsymbol-\mathrm iC\right)\hat{\rm R}
\tag{A-06}\label{A-06}   
\end{equation}

$-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\!$

Note that in equation \eqref{A-05} we have
\begin{align}
U_{13} & \e\tfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\left(\sigma_1 \p \sigma_3\right)\e\tfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}
\begin{bmatrix}
\:1  &  \hphantom{\m} 1 \vphantom{\tfrac{a}{b}}\:\:\\
\:1  &  \m 1 \vphantom{\tfrac{a}{b}}\:\:
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{A-07a}\label{A-07a}\\
U_{2} & \e\tfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\left(\du\p\mathrm i\sigma_2\right)\e\tfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}
\begin{bmatrix}
\hphantom{\m} 1  &  \:\:1\: \vphantom{\tfrac{a}{b}}\\
\m 1  &  \:\: 1 \:\vphantom{\tfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{A-07b}\label{A-07b}\\
\texttt{so} \qquad U_{2}^{\m 1} & \e\tfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\left(\du\m\mathrm i\sigma_2\right)\e\tfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}
\begin{bmatrix}
\:\:1  &  \m 1 \:\vphantom{\tfrac{a}{b}}\\
\:\:1  &  \hphantom{\m} 1 \:\vphantom{\tfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{A-07c}\label{A-07c}
\end{align}

Using above equations the unitary transformation $\:U_{FG}\:$ is
\begin{align}
U_{FG} & \e\tfrac12\left[\left(1\p\hat{\rm R}\right)U_{13}\p\left(1\m\hat{\rm R}\right)U_{2}^{\m 1}\right]
\nonumber\\
 & \e\tfrac{\sqrt{2}}{4}\left[\left(1\p\hat{\rm R}\right)
\begin{bmatrix}
\:1  &  \hphantom{\m} 1 \vphantom{\tfrac{a}{b}}\:\:\\
\:1  &  \m 1 \vphantom{\tfrac{a}{b}}\:\:
\end{bmatrix}
\p
\left(1\m\hat{\rm R}\right)
\begin{bmatrix}
\:\:1  &  \m 1 \:\vphantom{\tfrac{a}{b}}\\
\:\:1  &  \hphantom{\m} 1 \:\vphantom{\tfrac{a}{b}}
\end{bmatrix}\right]
\nonumber
\end{align}
that is
\begin{equation}
U_{FG}\e\tfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}
\begin{bmatrix}
\hphantom{\m}\mathrm  I  & \hphantom{\m}\hat{\rm R}\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\hphantom{-}\\
\hphantom{\m}\mathrm I  & \m\hat{\rm R}\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}\hphantom{\m}
\end{bmatrix}
\tag{A-08}\label{A-08}   
\end{equation}

The general case of Fulton-Gouterman type hermitian operators and transformations in this **ADDENDUM** yields the special case of the question under the following replacements
\begin{align}
\hat H_{FG} &  \qqlaqq \mathcal H
\tag{A-09.1}\label{A-09.1}\\
U_{FG} &  \qqlaqq \mathcal U^{\m 1}
\tag{A-09.2}\label{A-09.2}\\
\hat{\rm R} &  \qqlaqq \mathcal T
\tag{A-09.3}\label{A-09.3}\\
A &  \qqlaqq z\dfrac{\mathrm d }{\mathrm d z}
\tag{A-09.4}\label{A-09.4}\\
B &  \qqlaqq \gamma z\dfrac{\mathrm d }{\mathrm d z}\p\Delta
\tag{A-09.5}\label{A-09.5}\\
C &  \qqlaqq 0
\tag{A-09.6}\label{A-09.6}\\
D &  \qqlaqq g\left(z\p\dfrac{\mathrm d }{\mathrm d z}\right)
\tag{A-09.7}\label{A-09.7}\\
\hat{\rm L}_{\boldsymbol\pm} & \qqlaqq \mathcal H_{\boldsymbol\pm}
\tag{A-09.8}\label{A-09.8}
\end{align}

Comment: Reference : [Generalized Rabi models - diagonalization in the spin subspace](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.06721).

Comment: I miss your beautiful answers with the fantastic drawings $\ddot \smile$.

Answer (score 3):

I think the positioning of the parity operator matters, i.e. it should go to the right of each expression when you multiply the right two matrices?

You pick up extra minus signs because parity anticommutes with position and momentum.

Clever use of $T^2=1$! I like that a lot.